# Comparing data inside table

Tags: mysql, sql, nosql, compare

This is a fairly complex question, so I'll split it up:

### CHALLENGE

I have a table with the following structure:

- id (INT, UNIQUE)
- company (INT) -> links to another table containing companies
- costtype (INT)
- value (INT)

I need to compare companies by calculating the difference in values over all costtypes for each company. One company is used as the reference; the other companies should match the values for all costtypes for the reference company as close as possible. The results then need to be sorted by how close they match the reference company.

### FACTS

- We can assume all companies have the same costtypes
- The costtypes are not known in advance: they can be changed without notice
- The difference in costtype values between two companies should be calculated as follows: ABS([ref. company costtype value] - [other company costtype value]) ^ 2

### HYPOTHESES

The only way I can think of comparing this data is this:

- Get all different costtypes
- Get the values for these costtypes for the reference company
- Somehow group all costtypes for each company and use an incredibly long (automatically generated) query to compare all costtype values to the values for the reference company.

### QUESTIONS

- Is this even possible? I have no idea how I would compare multiple rows at once without JOINing all rows for one company, which would result in a giant query and would take forever.
- Is there a more efficient way to do this? Perhaps there's a standard solutions for these types of problems that I just don't know about? (And can't find on Google)
- Is there another database system (SQL, NoSQL, I'm open to everything) that might deal with these kinds of problems more efficiently than MySQL (which I'm using now)?

Thanks for reading the entire question; I know it's long, but it's very hard to explain. I've been struggling with this challenge for days and just can't seem to get a grip on things.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not ;) I work for a company that builds and maintains websites to compare health insurance companies. The current implementation only returns insurances that have at least the same coverage as the current insurance, but we want it to return the ones that are comparable, not superior ;).

Comment: ok let me give you an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a reference table which has following columns

```
id (autogen), compare_from_company_id, compare_to_company_id, value
```

fields explanation.

1. id - autogen field
2. ref company in your equation
3. other company in your equation
4. value of ABS([ref. company costtype value] - [other company costtype value]) ^ 2

Then you populate this table on the events when a primary record on your main table is changing. Then you can reference this new table easily with your other queries.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Problem is, each company has values for multiple costtypes. The actual comparison would be the the sum of (ABS([ref. company costtype value] - [other company costtype value]) ^ 2) for all costtypes.

Comment: so lets introduce ref.cost-type and dest.cost-type as two more fields?

Comment: Wait...so I'd build a reference table containing rows that represent the comparison between two companies for a specific costtype? That might just work! Thanks! (I'm sorry, I find it very hard to wrap my head around all those different layers of data ;-) )

Comment: @BramN you can use the unique id from your original table to identify the company_id, cost_type so you can reduce the size of your reference table